# UISlider in Android?

Tags: android, slider

is there some kind of widget for Android which does same job what UISlider for iPhone or jQuery slider for js ?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the SeekBar. It took me a while to find that under a different name, too.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html